# Draggable effect split screen

Tags: video, video-editor

I want to know that draggable split-screen effect is used in the next video? j-query?

[Draggable interact split screen video](https://youtu.be/TUDdciCNWWk)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that with simple masks. The main thing you need to do, it is to make several shots from same angels and same positions of the camera.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the interaction, is a plugin for example?

Comment: There is no interaction. It is just video, you can't interact with it. =)

Comment: thanks. Only interectaction in desktop version. Can you check this in http://earth2045.com/

Comment: Desktop? Like Windows/Linux application?

Comment: You can interact video in the web with mouse control. Regards

Comment: Ok, here you go: http://thenewcode.com/913/HTML5-Video-Before-and-After-Comparison-Slider

Comment: However, it is more coding question, so you chose wrong place to ask it ;)